# How to remove the duplicate entries in each dn session by shell

Tags: shell, ldap, ldif

I am facing problem in removing the duplicate entries. There are some duplicated `pwdHistory` in each session in a large `ldif` file. The entries are like:

```
dn: uid=mdwu701,ou=people,c=CN,dc=com
passwordRetryCount:0
passwordExpirationTime: 19700101000001Z
pwdHistory: 20171012140955412Z{SSHAS12}5PD67B30S1RgjybrVs61k1nErm/10USOnadfadf==
pwdHistory: 20171012140955412Z{SSHAS12}dafdaf32431adfJKHADKFHKAUD230324I-=23READLLJDASFEDFADF=-
pwdHistory: 2017101140654412Z{SSHAS12}5PD67B30S1RgjybrVs61k1nErm/10USOnkladjflajfda77DAFWE3DCsdfafeqwp+fupN
pwdHistory: 201710123064712Z{SSHAS12}37005PD67B30adsfjadfWQERQEWRVCADFADcfdaf98023=asdfad2/dafggalmjcp
pwdHistory: 2017101140654412Z{SSHAS12}5PD67B30S1RgjybrVs61k1nErm/10USOnkladjflajfda77DAFWE3DCsdfafeqwp+fupN
modifyTimestamp: 20171012165711Z
modifiersName: uid=mdwu701,ou=people,c=CN,dc=com
userPassword: {SSHA512}817XX1zaQaTAqV9wYE3Ao8orl7cBdCktr3Kgnuh1RgbC/vjfiaR2T/58KxEanS1Gzht0z1G1JhAigMLd8/fWsVQ32xATr8n
uid: mdwu701
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
sn: mdwu701
dn: mdwu701
createTimestamp: 2017010005943Z

dn: uid=mdwu702,ou=people,c=CN,dc=com
passwordRetryCount:0
passwordExpirationTime: 19700101000001Z
pwdHistory: 20171012140955412Z{SSHAS12}dafdaf32431adfJKHADKFHKAUD230324I-=23READLLJDASFEDFADF=-
pwdHistory: 201710123064712Z{SSHAS12}37005PD67B30adsfjadfWQERQEWRVCADFADcfdaf98023=asdfad2/dafggalmjcp
pwdHistory: 2017101140654412Z{SSHAS12}AAAAda322cdfadf=dafagedcdadafaErm/10USOnkladjflajfda77DAFWE3DCsdfafeqwp+adfe=0923=reafaP0+
pwdHistory: 201710123064712Z{SSHAS12}37005PD67B30adsfjadfWQERQEWRVCADFADcfdaf98023=asdfad2/dafggalmjcp
pwdHistory: 2017101140654412Z{SSHAS12}AAAAda322cdfadf=dafagedcdadafaErm/10USOnkladjflajfda77DAFWE3DCsdfafeqwp+adfe=0923=reafaP0+
modifyTimestamp: 20171211165311Z
modifiersName: uid=mdwu702,ou=people,c=CN,dc=com
userPassword: {SSHA512}jkladf23234kdfdafIKLJDF32-=ADSFCV/ADSFADF32DDAkjdafdgoojerqvccxadfad/adsfadsfre3werweqrpYRE6
uid: mdwu702
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
sn: mdwu702
dn: mdwu702
createTimestamp: 20171111115943Z

dn: uid=mdwu703,ou=people,c=CN,dc=com
passwordRetryCount:0
passwordExpirationTime: 19700101000001Z
pwdHistory: 201710123064712Z{SSHAS12}37005PD67B30adsfjadfWQERQEWRVCADFADcfdaf98023=asdfad2/dafggalmjcp
pwdHistory: 201710101408342412Z{SSHAS12}jybrVs61k1nErm/10USOnadfadf==5PD67B30S1Rg
pwdHistory: 2017101140654412Z{SSHAS12}adfadfafeweqxczz3134153SDGFADSREWE3DCbadfadfe33JKLL=ADFA32dafaf34dfeasdfalkdf0=
pwdHistory: 201710123064712Z{SSHAS12}37005PD67B30adsfjadfWQERQEWRVCADFADcfdaf98023=asdfad2/adfcvedtpdGFDE
pwdHistory: 2017101140654412Z{SSHAS12}adfadfafeweqxczz389VGHVHdfgdgfdjkkjkhkhkh3JKLL=ADFA32dafaf34dfeasdfadf2POI=
pwdHistory: 2017101140654412Z{SSHAS12}adfadfafeweqxczz3134153SDGFADSREWE3DCbadfadfe33JKLL=ADFA32dafaf34dfeasdfalkdf0=
modifyTimestamp: 20170912165707Z
modifiersName: uid=mdwu703,ou=people,c=CN,dc=com
userPassword: {SSHA512}817XXqerqer==-adsfad1zaQaTAqV9wWsVQ32xATr8nzzYE3Ao8orl7cBdCktr3Kgnuh1RgbCxf87234dfkljcadsfldfg23d/
uid: mdwu703
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
sn: mdwu703
dn: mdwu703
createTimestamp: 20171222224532Z
```

There are some duplicated in `pwdHistory` which need to be removed. I tried to use

```
awk '!/pwdHistory/ || !seen[$0]++' test.ldif
```

to clean up the duplicate entries. However, it will remove all the duplicated `pwdHistory`. I want to remove the duplicated `pwdHistory` in each `dn`.

Comment: Can you load this data into a database, then it would be very simple to remove the duplicates. Otherwise, experiment with adding the `dn` value into the key of  your `seen[]` array. Good luck.

Comment: I'd also recommend reading [mcve] and reduce the size of your test data. If you can get this to work with 6 line records that are 30 chars wide, won't it still work when you use your data. AND, in the same vein,  you'll do well to read, review and take to heart the items on this page : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Search for "Before asking about Problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question" .Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your infor, acutually there are two diffirent attributes with the same value, and i rename that in the same attribute after export the data from the database.